# https://<salesforce_instance>/cometd/replay/37.0 giving unsupported API version

Tags: api, salesforce, streaming

I am using EMP connector to use salesforce streaming API, but on specifying API version 37.0 I am getting below error, but as per documentation it should be working fine as API version 37.0 is released API

> [{"channel":"/meta/handshake","error":"400::Unsupported API version.
>   Only API versions '35.0' and '36.0' are
>   supported.","successful":false}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in EMP connector which is now fixed in latest EMP connector code